# Why can't I insertAdjecentHTML into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't successfully use

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span style="color:red">Danger</span>')
```

```html
<textarea>TEXT</textarea>
```

in my code. Chrome inserts the text escaped, FF doesn't show the node. Is there any documentation about this behavior?

**Update**: Beside the type on the function name it doesn't work (which is expected) because `<textarea>` only supports text content as specified in the [HTML5 Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-textarea-element) (see "*Content model*: Text").
The method `insertAdjacentHTML` is inherited from HTMLElement -> Element.

**Sidenote**: Chrome and Firefox behave different if your first create an element and then append it (append but don't show) instead of showing the html as text.

Comment: Works fine on FF for me (text gets inserted into the textarea)

Comment: `insertAdjecentHTML` is missing a `t`, it should be `insertAdjacentHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child nodes of a textarea:

- Can only be text nodes. Element descendants are forbidden.
- Represent the *default* value of the textarea, not the current value. Manipulating it is not guaranteed to update the current value.

If you want to change the value of a textarea, use the `value` property.

```
document.querySelector('textarea').value += '<span style="color:red">Danger</span>';
```

If you want a *formatted* and *editable* control, then don't use a textarea. See [making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).